# got compile error when use clock_gettime in c99

Tags: c, c99

when I use clock_gettime in my code snippet, and compile with flag -std=c99, I got a error like this:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_gettime'
error: 'CLOCK_REALTIME' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

and I have included the file 'time.h'.
anyone knows how to fix it.

Comment: It will help if you mention specifics of your environment, what compiler, what libc, etc. Also helps to show the code in question, like the `#include` any relevant macros you have `#define` for.

Comment: clock_gettime is not standard C99, nor is CLOCK_REALTIME. But they are POSIX.

Comment: thanks, I have compiled successfully with flag -std=gnu99

Answer (score 8):

in your original code with -std=c99, try adding

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
```

the man page for clock_gettime indicates this is a necessary feature test macro requirement.

Comment: Please note that this definition must be above the #include directive for `time.h`.

Comment: Actually, the symbol is not intended to be changed directly. Prefer instead using a different compiler flag such as --std=gnu99. It will have a more reliable and consistent impact on the flag.

Comment: gcc 9.3.0 doesn't like this: error: operator '>=' has no left operand
   30 | #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L